# HTML video tag to fill whole screen on phones

Tags: javascript, html, video, getusermedia

Right now, I am trying to create a "snapchat" kind of web app, for my education.
The app makes use of HTML5 tags, like video and canvas.

Then i use getUserMedia to get the camera output, but my problem is that i can't get the video tag to fill the whole screen.

I have tried everything from width: 100%; height: 100%;, height: 100vh, jquery, but that messed up the getUserMedia function, so it didn't even work.

Right now, this is my code:
HTML File:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="da">
    <head>
        <title>Camera output</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <video id="video" autoplay></video>
        <button id="snap" class="snapButton">Snap Photo</button>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>

        <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS File:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#video {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    transform-origin: center center;
}
```

JS File:

```
function setElementFullScreen(selector) {
     var ele= $(selector);
     // Set left/top, can be done in directly in css
     ele.css('top',0).css('left',0);
     // Set size from window
     ele.height($(window).height()).width($(window).width());
 }

 $(document).ready(function () {
     setElementFullScreen('video');
 });

// Add resize event
$(window).on('resize', function () {
    setElementFullScreen('video');
});

// Put event listeners into place
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    var mediaConfig =  { video: true };
    var errBack = function(e) {
        console.log('An error has occurred!', e)
    };

    // Put video listeners into place
    if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConfig).then(function(stream) {
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            video.play();
        });
    }

    /* Legacy code below! */
    else if(navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
        navigator.getUserMedia(mediaConfig, function(stream) {
            video.src = stream;
            video.play();
        }, errBack);
    } else if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(mediaConfig, function(stream){
            video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
            video.play();
        }, errBack);
    } else if(navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { // Mozilla-prefixed
        navigator.mozGetUserMedia(mediaConfig, function(stream){
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            video.play();
        }, errBack);
    }

    // Trigger photo take
    document.getElementById('snap').addEventListener('click', function() {
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
    });
}, false);
```

So my question is: Is there any way to make the video tag fill every bit of a phone screen? I tried on desktop, it had no problem with filling in horizontally.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 <video id="video" autoplay></video>

 <script>
     var elem = document.getElementById("myvideo");
     if(elem.requestFullscreen) {
         elem.requestFullscreen();
     }
 </script>
```

This will ask the browser to use full screen on video playback. I think you'll have some issues with browser compatibility on mobile devices.

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API

Edit:

Seems to be your `ele.height($(window).height()).width($(window).width());` giving you trouble. Try logging `window.height()` and `window.width()` to your debugging console to determine what it returns.

If you haven't already, look at this:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp

Here is a tutorial with similar application examples:

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I dont want it to go fullscreen, because i am going to have buttons on top of the element. I want it to fill the whole background/screen of a phone

Comment: That is not at all what I perceived your question was. Can you post some more of your code? Specifically interested in your `CSS` and the wrapper for video and button overlay.

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't that clear. I have updated my question with my html, css and js file.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a snipplet with working example.

```js
function setElementFullScreen(selector) {
    var ele = $(selector);
    // Get window size
    var maxWidth = $(window).width();
    var maxHeight = $(window).height();
    // Get video size
    var videoWidth = ele.width();
    var videoHeight = ele.height();
    // Calcul relative size 
    if (maxWidth > maxHeight) {
        var relatifWidth = videoWidth / (videoHeight / maxHeight);
        var relatifHeight = maxHeight;
    } else {
        var relatifWidth = maxWidth;
        var relatifHeight = videoHeight / (videoWidth / maxWidth);
    }
    // Check if result size is not bigger than canvas size
    if (relatifWidth > maxWidth) {
        relatifWidth = maxWidth;
        relatifHeight = (relatifWidth * videoHeight) / videoWidth;
    } else if (relatifHeight > maxHeight) {
        relatifHeight = maxHeight;
        relatifWidth = (relatifHeight * videoWidth) / videoHeight;
    }
    // Set size from window
    ele.height(relatifHeight).width(relatifWidth);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    setElementFullScreen('#video');

    // Put event listeners into place
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var video = document.getElementById('video');
        var mediaConfig = {video: true};
        var errBack = function (e) {
            console.log('An error has occurred!', e)
        };

        // Put video listeners into place
        if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConfig).then(function (stream) {
                video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                video.play();
            });
        }

        /* Legacy code below! */
        else if (navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
            navigator.getUserMedia(mediaConfig, function (stream) {
                video.src = stream;
                video.play();
            }, errBack);
        } else if (navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(mediaConfig, function (stream) {
                video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
                video.play();
            }, errBack);
        } else if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { // Mozilla-prefixed
            navigator.mozGetUserMedia(mediaConfig, function (stream) {
                video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                video.play();
            }, errBack);
        }

        // Trigger photo take
        document.getElementById('snap').addEventListener('click', function () {
            context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
        });
    }, false);

});

// Add resize event
$(window).on('resize', function () {
    setElementFullScreen('video');
});
```

```css
video {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="video" autoplay>
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
</video>
<br>
<button id="snap" class="snapButton">Snap Photo</button>
<br>
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```

Comment: It didn't seem to work. If i change the selector from video to my button, it works, and makes the button fill the screen, but my video element stays the same size. I have updated my question with my full code, if you want to take a look.

Comment: I try some thing, tell me if that help you.